# Woo commerce using add_fee to add discount to cart not saving discount amount the admin backend when guest user is shopping

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

Today I spent full day solving one single problem of not able to display custom discount in the backend order management of woocommerce plugin,
I added the discount on cart calling the woocommerce add_fee method from functions.php

The discount is working fine for registered user but when guest user is shopping the only problem is that the discount is not being in the order object.

Any help would be most appreciated.